# Call to CIContext.FromOptions crashes in iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS app, I continuously receive CIImage instances that I need to convert to CGImage instance. Here is the relevant code:

```
CIContext cicontext = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
CGImage cgimage = cicontext.CreateCGImage(ciimage, ciimage.Extent);
...
cgimage.Dispose();
cicontext.Dispose();
```

Things work fine for the first 100 or so calls. After that, I get a crash in the application. Here is the stack trace:

```
critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x21866077 _sigtramp + 42
critical:   3   CoreImage                           0x24a352b9 <redacted> + 64
critical:   4   CoreImage                           0x24a6c005 <redacted> + 292
critical:   5   CoreImage                           0x24a6c237 <redacted> + 18
critical:   6   CoreImage                           0x24a4b431 <redacted> + 512
critical:   7   CoreImage                           0x24a47d5b <redacted> + 734
critical:   8   CoreImage                           0x24a47a55 <redacted> + 52
critical:   9   MyApp                               0x00fa4eb4 wrapper_managed_to_native_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 108
critical:   10  MyApp                               0x00f41a5c CoreImage_CIContext_FromOptions_Foundation_NSDictionary + 120
critical:   11  MyApp                               0x00f41868 CoreImage_CIContext_FromOptions_CoreImage_CIContextOptions + 48
```

Basically, some logic in `CIContext.FromOptions` causes it to crash.

For now, I have made cicontext object a static variable that is initialized just once. This seems to take care of the crash. However, I would appreciate it if you have any insight. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those running into this problem, this fix worked for us:

1. Call `cicontext = CIContext.FromOptions(null)` just once and hold on to the return value, either as a member variable or a static variable.
2. After calling `CreateCGImage` call `cicontext.ClearCaches()`. If this is not done, you will eventually run out of memory.

Hope this helps. Regards.